# Make "from heaven" effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I have a picture and I'd like to replicate this effect, like "from heaven":

[http://imgur.com/a/fEULt](https://imgur.com/a/fEULt)

I already have a picture without background but I want to know how can I replicate that blurry effect on the edges.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? This is a very basic Photoshop skill, pretty sure there are plenty of tutorials if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

select the areas you want for the pic of the person. Then Go to refine edge and turn the "feather" and "Smooth" up a bit util it gets how you want it.